# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext

Tags: java, jaxb, classcastexception, moxy

I'm trying to use the MOxy implementation of the JAXB specification. One of the primary reasons is to make sure unmapped elements in the XML file are not lost during marshaling back the content of the objects. I've been hitting the ClassCastException even though (I think) I have the jaxb.properties file in the right location. Following is my file organization (as well as how it is organized in Eclipse) :

- \zMain.java
- \Config.java
- \jaxb.properties (specifying to use MOxy has the JAXB
  provider - javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory)

I have some basic stuff written to validate functioning of this implementation.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class zMain {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         File xml = new File("sampleconfig.xml");
         Document document = db.parse(xml);
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
         Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
         Config cfg = (Config) binder.unmarshal(document);
         // do nothing
         binder.updateXML(cfg);
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
         t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
         t.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3");
         t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(100);
      }
   }
}
```

Executing this JAR throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
```

eclipselink-2.4.0.jar is in my classpath (else I'm assuming it would've been a ClassNotFoundException or a compilation error).

Though unlikely, could there be any environment setting that causes my imports to be overridden ? Any pointers on what's been done wrong here would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have jaxb impl jar in your classpath. If yes, then remove it because jaxb classes should be bunlded in your jdk library (from java 6).

Answer (score 2):

In your example the `jaxb.properties` file must be in the same package as your `Config` class.

Once you solve your current issue, the following import is going to cause you problems.  `JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class)` is going to return you an instance of `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext` so you should import that instead.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext;
```

Below is a link to an example of GitHub that leverages a `jaxb.properties` file to specify MOXy as the JAXB provider.

- https://github.com/bdoughan/blog20110819

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

**Note:**

The current version of EclipseLink is 2.4.1, you can download it from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/